# NodeJS - Creating empty array results in array with a lot of nulls

Tags: arrays, node.js, socket.io

I am creating a Node.js chat using socket.io
The problem is that when I see the `console.log` of `history` I see an array with A LOT of nulls and at the end my history entries
`[null,null,null......[ { username: 'Nobody Example', message: '231', date: '03/21/2013 14:23:58' } ]]`

How come these nulls are in the array?
Here is a part of my code.

```
var history = [];

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {

    socket.on('send', function (message) {
        var date = time();

        io.sockets.in(socket.room).emit('message', socket.username, message, date);

        history[socket.room].push({ username: socket.username, message: message, date: date });

        console.log(history);

    });

    socket.on('joinroom', function (room, username) {
        socket.room = room;
        socket.join(room);

        if ( typeof history[room] === 'undefined' )
            history[room] = [];

    });

});
```

Edit for more details:

The problem is in the 'joinroom' event when creating the empty array for each room.
Here are few tests that I've made:

```
socket.on('joinroom', function (room, username) {
    socket.room = room;
    socket.join(room);

    console.log(typeof history[room] == 'undefined');
    history[room] = [];
    console.log(typeof history[room] == 'undefined');
    console.log(JSON.stringify(history));
});
```

The console logs:

```
true
false
[null,null,null,null,..................,null,[]]
```

Comment: I think you want `history` to be an object instead of an array: `var history = {};`

Comment: Then how am I going to add the history entry for each room? `.push()` is supported only by Array.

Comment: You're not pushing onto `history` directly, but on arrays *in* `history`, so that would work just fine.

Comment: When I change `history = {}` nothing really changes. The nulls are still there. I think there is something really messed up with node.js, because I test my code in the browser console (because it's just a simple work with arrays and objects) and there I get correct results (array without nulls).

Comment: Those nulls are a tell-tale sign of indexing an array with a large value: `var a = []; a[23] = 1; console.log(JSON.stringify(a));`

Comment: Oh, this is it! My room names are starting from 100001++. Thanks! Post your comment as answer to accept it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have an empty array and index it with a large number (like your room id's), all slots in the array before that number are filled with `undefined` (which translates to `null` in JSON).

So try making history an object instead:

```
var history = {};
```

Comment: Ooook, which translates to `null` in JSON, that is what led me here. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

try below code changing to object(hash);

```
var history = {};

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {

socket.on('send', function (message) {
    var date = time();

    io.sockets.in(socket.room).emit('message', socket.username, message, date);

    if(history[socket.room] !== undefined) {
          history[socket.room].push = { username: socket.username, message: message, date: date   };
    } else {
        history[socket.room] = [{ username: socket.username, message: message, date: date   }];
    }

    console.log(history);

});
```

Comment: This is wrong, because it will keep only the last entry for each room. `history[socket.room] =` has to be array.