# Calendar List not returning results when called in nodejs application

Tags: google-calendar-api

```
let scopes = ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly"];
if (checker(googleKey)&&checker(jwtClient)) {
    jwtClient = new google.auth.JWT(
        googleKey.client_email,
        null,
        googleKey.private_key, scopes,
        null
    );
        jwtClient.authorize(function jwtAuth(err, tokens) {
            if (err) {
                res.json({ error: "Failed to execute auth command " });
                return;
            }

            let calendar = google.calendar('v3');
            calendar.calendarList.list({
                auth: jwtClient
            }, function(err, resp) {
                if (err || !resp.items) {
                    res.json({ error: "Failed to execute calendar list request " });
                    return;
                }
                let calendars = resp.items.map(cal => { if (cal.summary) return { id: cal.id, txt: cal.summary } });
                res.json(calendars);
            });
        });
    }
```

So the above code makes a jwt Authorized call for the calendar list in an account with an enabled calendar api. I can even see the successful requests made when I go to my console, however the results I get from nodejs is an empty array, where as if I test it in the api explorer I get the proper results.. whats going on?

Comment: Based from this [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15551433/5832311), if you have an empty array and index it with a large number, all slots in the array before that number are filled with undefined (which translates to null in JSON). Also, you may refer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36029935/5832311). *If you want to grant the service account access to your Google Calendar you will need to take the service account email address and share your Google calendar with it like you would share it with any other user.* Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks the issue I had was I had not shared access to the calendars. I used this [link](https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/37082?hl=en). I dnt know what you were talking about with the array index issue, My code cleanly calls a map on the data from google. I am not referring to any array indices directly.

Answer (score 2):

it's a one year old question but maybe someone else benefit from the answer. You should use "data" instead of "items" in the code. Here is working example:

```
async function listCalendars() {
  // console.log( calendar.calendarList);
  calendar.calendarList.list({
      auth: oauth2Client,
      maxResults: 100
    },
    function (err, result) {
      console.log(result.data.items);
    }
  );
}

listCalendars().catch(console.error);
```

Comment: Hey.. Thanks for the reply. I will try it and get back.